# FactoryGirl Rspec Model Test Failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec

I have an app to track customers, jobs and hours (and such).  I'm using rails 3.2.2 and rspec_rails 2.13.0.  I'm following the pdf book everydayrailsrspec by Aaron Sumner.

My relationships are, customers can have many jobs, jobs can have many hours.

I'm testing my models.  Customers and jobs tests all pass fine.  It is my hours tests I cannot get to work and I've only just started on it.  I can't get the 'test factory' test to pass.  Sigh.

Hours Factory:

```
# spec/factories/hours.rb

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :hour do
    job = FactoryGirl.create(:job)
    job_id job.id
    first_name "John"
    last_name  "Smith"
    hours 8
    date_worked "2013-04-27"
    description "Did some work"
  end
end
```

Hours needs a job_id, so I create a job using the jobs factory to get a job_id from it. I do this same thing in my jobs factory to get a customer_id and it works fine.  This is the line that 'I believe' the error is balking on.  It seems to be telling me it doesn't see my jobs factory.

Error output (partial) - see first and last lines:

```
/Users/johndcowan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/factory_girl-4.2.0/lib/factory_girl/registry.rb:24:in `find': Factory not registered: job (ArgumentError)
from /Users/johndcowan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/factory_girl-4.2.0/lib/factory_girl/decorator.rb:10:in `method_missing'
from /Users/johndcowan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/factory_girl-4.2.0/lib/factory_girl.rb:71:in `factory_by_name'
from /Users/johndcowan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/factory_girl-4.2.0/lib/factory_girl/factory_runner.rb:12:in `run'
from /Users/johndcowan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p318/gems/factory_girl-4.2.0/lib/factory_girl/strategy_syntax_method_registrar.rb:19:in `block in define_singular_strategy_method'
from /Users/johndcowan/MyWebSites/drywall/spec/factories/hours.rb:5:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
...
```

The first line in output has: Factory not registered: job (ArgumentError)  Does this mean it is not seeing my jobs factory?

Line 5 in the Factory is: job = FactoryGirl.create(:job)

Jobs factory in case it helps:

```
# spec/factories/jobs.rb

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :job do
    # need a customer for the customer_id field
    customer = FactoryGirl.create(:customer)
    customer_id customer.id
    sequence(:name) { |n| "Job#{n}" }
    sequence(:address) { |x| "#{x} Main Str" }
    city "Cortland"
    state "NY"
    zip "13045"
    sequence(:phone) { |y| "607-75#{y}-1234" }
    description "Drywall Work"
  end
end
```

My spec test

```
# spec/models/hour_spec.rb
require 'spec_helper'

describe Hour do
  it "has a valid factory" do
    FactoryGirl.create(:hour).should be_valid
  end
end
```

Thanks for any insight.
--jc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The association definition is incorrect. Try to use the documented way

```
factory :hour do
  job #this is enough
  first_name "John"
  last_name  "Smith"
  hours 8
  date_worked "2013-04-27"
  description "Did some work"
end
```

Comment: Billy Chan, you are D'man.   Thank you!  Always learnin' somethin' in this forum.